# Scapy --TypeError: unbound method copy() must be called with UDP instance as first argument

Tags: python-2.7, udp, typeerror, scapy

I am writing a python script that creates UDP packets at layer 2 with Scapy.

However, I continually get a "TypeError" when including UDP() options/attributes in the definition of the packet.

Code:

```
Return_Data = sendp( Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", type=0x800) \
/ IP(version=4L, ihl=5L, tos=0x0, len=64,                 \
id=0, flags=0, frag=0L, ttl=64, proto=UDP,              \
chksum = 30495, src="xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", dst="xxx.xxx.x.x") /  \
UDP(sport=31123, dport=31123, chksum=0x6f21, len=30) / Raw(load=Payload) )
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "EthCfgRx_Test_3.py", line 20, in 
UDP(sport=31123, dport=31123, chksum=0x6f21, len=30) / Raw(load=Payload) )

File "/home/watouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 349, in **div**
    cloneB = other.copy()

File "/home/watouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 200, in copy
    clone.fields = self.copy_fields_dict(self.fields)

File "/home/watouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 382, in copy_fields_dict
    for fname, fval in six.iteritems(fields)}

File "/home/watouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 382, in 
    for fname, fval in six.iteritems(fields)}

File "/home/watouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 377, in copy_field_value
    return self.get_field(fieldname).do_copy(value)

File "/home/watouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 86, in do_copy
    return x.copy()

TypeError: unbound method copy() must be called with UDP instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Any Advice?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Scapy will bind automatically the packets.

The wrong part seems to be `Proto=UDP`. Proto should be a number, not a class.

When doing the `/` operation, the Proto will be automatically provided, so you don’t need to specify it